# Long Table with multicolumn width problem

Tags: longtable, multirow

I am trying to use longtable package with multirow package, as shown in the example below, but the long table width exceeded the page width, could anyone help with this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\title{A longtable example}

\begin{document}

\begin{center} 

 \begin{longtable}{|p{1cm}|p{3cm}|p{12cm}|}
 \caption{List Of Quality Metrics Used} \label{tab:qm} \\

  \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Ref.}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Metrics Used}}  \\ \hline 
   \endfirsthead

  \multicolumn{3}{c}%
   {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
  \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Ref.}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Metrics Used}}  \\ \hline 
  \endhead

   \hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
   \endfoot

    \hline \hline
    \endlastfoot

    ref1 & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{ LOC-WORKED-ON, MAX-LOC-WORKED-ON, AVG-LOC-WORKED-ON, MAX-COMMITS, 
    AVG-COMMITS, MAX-LOC-ADDED, AVG-LOC-ADDED, MAX-LOC-DELETED, AVG-LOC-DELETED, MAX-LOC-WORKED, AVG- 
    LOC-WORKED,MAX-CODECHURN, AVG-CODECHURN, MAX-CHANGESET, AVG-CHANGESET, MAX-TIME-DIFF,MIN-TIME- 
    DIFF,AVG-TIME-DIFF, SINGLE-COMMITS} \\ \hline
    ref2 & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{ WMC, DIT, NOC, CBO, RFC, LCOM, Ca, Ce, NPM, LCOM3, LOC, DAM,MOA, MFA, 
    CAM, IC, CBM, AMC, Max-CC, Avg-CC.} \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{ref3}  & Dataset PC3 \& PC4: & LOC-BLANK
     BRACNH-COUNT,
     CALL-PAIRS,
     LOC-CODE-AND-COMMENTS,
     LOC-COMMENTS,
     CONDITION-COUNT,
     CYCLOMATIC-COMPLEXITY,
     CYCLIMATIC-DENSITY,
     DECISION-COUNT,
     DECISION-DENSITY,
     EDGE-COUNT,
     ESSENTIAL-COMPLEXITY,
     ESSENTIAL-DENSITY,
     LOC-EXECUTABLE,
     PARAMETER-COUNT,
     HALSTEAD-CONTENT,
     HALSREAD-DOFFICULTY,
     HALSTEAD-EFFORT,
     HALSTEAD-ERROR-EST,
     HALSTEAD-LENGTH,
     HALSTEAD LEVEL,
     HALSTEAD-VOLUME,
     MAINTENANCE-SEVERITY,
     MODIFIED-CONDITION-COUNT,
     MULTIPLE-CONDITION-COUNT,
     NODE-COUNT,
     NORMALIZED-CYCLOMATIC-COMPLEXITY,
     NUM-OPERANDS, 
     NUM-OPERATORS,
     NUM-UNIQUE-OPERANDS,
     NUM-UNIQYE-OPERATORS,
     NUMBER-OF-LINES,
     PERCENT-COMMENTS,
     LOC-TOTAL  \\ \cline{2-3}
                & Dataset KC2 & LOC-EXECUTABLE,
     CYCLOMATIC-COMPLEXITY,
     ESSENTIAL-COMPLEXITY,
     DESIGN-COMPLEXITY,
     NUM-OPERATORS-AND-OPERANDS,
     HALSTEAD-VOLUME,
     HALSTEAD-DIFFICULTY,
     HALSTEAD-INTEELIGENCE,
     HALSTEAD-EFFORT,
     HALSTEAD-NUM-DELIVERED-BUGS,
     HALSTEAD-PROG-TIME,
     HALSTEAD-CODE-LINE-COUNT,
     HALSTEAD-CODE-AND-COMMENT-LINE-COUNT,
     NUM-UNIQUE-OPERATORS,
     NUM-UNIQUE-OPERANDS,
     NUM-OPERATORS,
     NUM-OPERANDS,
     BRANCH-COUNT \\ \hline                            

     \end{longtable}

     \end{center}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're defining the column width in the `p` type columns, and the overall width of the three columns is more than 145 pt wider than your text width.

Comment: Wouldn't a list like environment such as itemize or description  be better suited for this kind of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes your table in the following ways:

- use only the available `\linewidth`
- remove `\multirow` (it's useless in this example as the contents won't stay on the same page most likely and the alignment doesn't work automatically anyway for `p`-type columns)
- use `\raggedright` in the cells with much content (for that the `array` package is loaded and the `L` type column defined)
- use `\dimexpr` to calculate the available width somewhat automatically (you can change the values of `\myfirstcol` and `\mysecondcol` to get the result you want)
- use `L` columns also in the joined cells of the first and second row (with `\dimexpr` to calculate the width)
- I removed `center` around `longtable`, that isn't necessary anyways, as `longtable` centres the tables (if you don't manually specify another alignment) and `center` only results in unwanted vertical space here (also the table is as wide as the text block allows, so it is always centred anyway)
- use `\caption` to format the continued caption as well (if you use an empty optional argument, `longtable` won't add this caption to the list of tables, shown in my MWE), I also altered the text of that follow-up caption.
- I used `\extrarowheight` to space out the cells a bit more (this gives better looks combined with `\hline` and `\cline` rules).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\title{A longtable example}

\newlength\myfirstcol
\newlength\mysecondcol
\newlength\mythirdcol
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\begingroup
\setlength\myfirstcol{8mm}
\setlength\mysecondcol{2cm}
\setlength\mythirdcol
  {\dimexpr\linewidth-\myfirstcol-\mysecondcol-6\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
 \begin{longtable}{|p{\myfirstcol}|L{\mysecondcol}|L{\mythirdcol}|}
 \caption{List Of Quality Metrics Used} \label{tab:qm} \\

  \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Ref.}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Metrics Used}}  \\ \hline 
   \endfirsthead

   \caption[]{List Of Quality Metrics Used (continued)} \\
  \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Ref.}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Metrics Used}}  \\ \hline 
  \endhead

   \hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
   \endfoot

    \hline \hline
    \endlastfoot

    ref1 &
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\dimexpr\mythirdcol+\mysecondcol+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}{ LOC-WORKED-ON, MAX-LOC-WORKED-ON, AVG-LOC-WORKED-ON, MAX-COMMITS, 
    AVG-COMMITS, MAX-LOC-ADDED, AVG-LOC-ADDED, MAX-LOC-DELETED, AVG-LOC-DELETED, MAX-LOC-WORKED, AVG- 
    LOC-WORKED,MAX-CODECHURN, AVG-CODECHURN, MAX-CHANGESET, AVG-CHANGESET, MAX-TIME-DIFF,MIN-TIME- 
    DIFF,AVG-TIME-DIFF, SINGLE-COMMITS} \\ \hline
    ref2 &
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\dimexpr\mythirdcol+\mysecondcol+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}{ WMC, DIT, NOC, CBO, RFC, LCOM, Ca, Ce, NPM, LCOM3, LOC, DAM,MOA, MFA, 
    CAM, IC, CBM, AMC, Max-CC, Avg-CC.} \\ \hline
    ref3  & Dataset PC3 \& PC4: & LOC-BLANK
     BRACNH-COUNT,
     CALL-PAIRS,
     LOC-CODE-AND-COMMENTS,
     LOC-COMMENTS,
     CONDITION-COUNT,
     CYCLOMATIC-COMPLEXITY,
     CYCLIMATIC-DENSITY,
     DECISION-COUNT,
     DECISION-DENSITY,
     EDGE-COUNT,
     ESSENTIAL-COMPLEXITY,
     ESSENTIAL-DENSITY,
     LOC-EXECUTABLE,
     PARAMETER-COUNT,
     HALSTEAD-CONTENT,
     HALSREAD-DOFFICULTY,
     HALSTEAD-EFFORT,
     HALSTEAD-ERROR-EST,
     HALSTEAD-LENGTH,
     HALSTEAD LEVEL,
     HALSTEAD-VOLUME,
     MAINTENANCE-SEVERITY,
     MODIFIED-CONDITION-COUNT,
     MULTIPLE-CONDITION-COUNT,
     NODE-COUNT,
     NORMALIZED-CYCLOMATIC-COMPLEXITY,
     NUM-OPERANDS, 
     NUM-OPERATORS,
     NUM-UNIQUE-OPERANDS,
     NUM-UNIQYE-OPERATORS,
     NUMBER-OF-LINES,
     PERCENT-COMMENTS,
     LOC-TOTAL  \\ \cline{2-3}
                & Dataset KC2 & LOC-EXECUTABLE,
     CYCLOMATIC-COMPLEXITY,
     ESSENTIAL-COMPLEXITY,
     DESIGN-COMPLEXITY,
     NUM-OPERATORS-AND-OPERANDS,
     HALSTEAD-VOLUME,
     HALSTEAD-DIFFICULTY,
     HALSTEAD-INTEELIGENCE,
     HALSTEAD-EFFORT,
     HALSTEAD-NUM-DELIVERED-BUGS,
     HALSTEAD-PROG-TIME,
     HALSTEAD-CODE-LINE-COUNT,
     HALSTEAD-CODE-AND-COMMENT-LINE-COUNT,
     NUM-UNIQUE-OPERATORS,
     NUM-UNIQUE-OPERANDS,
     NUM-OPERATORS,
     NUM-OPERANDS,
     BRANCH-COUNT \\ \hline                            
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful :), how can I mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest one of the two following redesigns. With this approach, your table fits onto a single page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabdescr}{description}{1}
\setlist[tabdescr]{before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\raggedright,
                   after=\end{minipage}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{List Of Quality Metrics Used} \label{tab:qm}
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|0l|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}0{X}|}

  \hline \multicolumn{1}{|0c|}{\textbf{Ref.}} & \multicolumn{1}{0c|}{\textbf{Metrics Used}}  \\ \hline 

    ref1 &
    LOC-WORKED-ON, MAX-LOC-WORKED-ON, AVG-LOC-WORKED-ON, MAX-COMMITS, 
    AVG-COMMITS, MAX-LOC-ADDED, AVG-LOC-ADDED, MAX-LOC-DELETED, AVG-LOC-DELETED, MAX-LOC-WORKED, AVG- 
    LOC-WORKED,MAX-CODECHURN, AVG-CODECHURN, MAX-CHANGESET, AVG-CHANGESET, MAX-TIME-DIFF,MIN-TIME- 
    DIFF,AVG-TIME-DIFF, SINGLE-COMMITS \\ \hline
    ref2 &
     WMC, DIT, NOC, CBO, RFC, LCOM, Ca, Ce, NPM, LCOM3, LOC, DAM,MOA, MFA, 
    CAM, IC, CBM, AMC, Max-CC, Avg-CC\\ \hline
    ref3  & \textit{Dataset PC3 \& PC4:}  LOC-BLANK
     BRACNH-COUNT,
     CALL-PAIRS,
     LOC-CODE-AND-COMMENTS,
     LOC-COMMENTS,
     CONDITION-COUNT,
     CYCLOMATIC-COMPLEXITY,
     CYCLIMATIC-DENSITY,
     DECISION-COUNT,
     DECISION-DENSITY,
     EDGE-COUNT,
     ESSENTIAL-COMPLEXITY,
     ESSENTIAL-DENSITY,
     LOC-EXECUTABLE,
     PARAMETER-COUNT,
     HALSTEAD-CONTENT,
     HALSREAD-DOFFICULTY,
     HALSTEAD-EFFORT,
     HALSTEAD-ERROR-EST,
     HALSTEAD-LENGTH,
     HALSTEAD LEVEL,
     HALSTEAD-VOLUME,
     MAINTENANCE-SEVERITY,
     MODIFIED-CONDITION-COUNT,
     MULTIPLE-CONDITION-COUNT,
     NODE-COUNT,
     NORMALIZED-CYCLOMATIC-COMPLEXITY,
     NUM-OPERANDS, 
     NUM-OPERATORS,
     NUM-UNIQUE-OPERANDS,
     NUM-UNIQYE-OPERATORS,
     NUMBER-OF-LINES,
     PERCENT-COMMENTS,
     LOC-TOTAL  \\ \cline{2-2}
                & \textit{Dataset KC2} LOC-EXECUTABLE,
     CYCLOMATIC-COMPLEXITY,
     ESSENTIAL-COMPLEXITY,
     DESIGN-COMPLEXITY,
     NUM-OPERATORS-AND-OPERANDS,
     HALSTEAD-VOLUME,
     HALSTEAD-DIFFICULTY,
     HALSTEAD-INTEELIGENCE,
     HALSTEAD-EFFORT,
     HALSTEAD-NUM-DELIVERED-BUGS,
     HALSTEAD-PROG-TIME,
     HALSTEAD-CODE-LINE-COUNT,
     HALSTEAD-CODE-AND-COMMENT-LINE-COUNT,
     NUM-UNIQUE-OPERATORS,
     NUM-UNIQUE-OPERANDS,
     NUM-OPERATORS,
     NUM-OPERANDS,
     BRANCH-COUNT \\ \hline                            
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\caption{List Of Quality Metrics Used} \label{tab:qm}
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

  \toprule
  Ref. & Metrics Used \\ 
  \midrule 

    ref1 &
    LOC-WORKED-ON, MAX-LOC-WORKED-ON, AVG-LOC-WORKED-ON, MAX-COMMITS, 
    AVG-COMMITS, MAX-LOC-ADDED, AVG-LOC-ADDED, MAX-LOC-DELETED, AVG-LOC-DELETED, MAX-LOC-WORKED, AVG- 
    LOC-WORKED,MAX-CODECHURN, AVG-CODECHURN, MAX-CHANGESET, AVG-CHANGESET, MAX-TIME-DIFF,MIN-TIME- 
    DIFF,AVG-TIME-DIFF, SINGLE-COMMITS \\ 
    \midrule
    ref2 &
     WMC, DIT, NOC, CBO, RFC, LCOM, Ca, Ce, NPM, LCOM3, LOC, DAM,MOA, MFA, 
    CAM, IC, CBM, AMC, Max-CC, Avg-CC\\
    \midrule
    ref3  & \begin{tabdescr}\item{Dataset PC3 \& PC4:}  LOC-BLANK
     BRACNH-COUNT,
     CALL-PAIRS,
     LOC-CODE-AND-COMMENTS,
     LOC-COMMENTS,
     CONDITION-COUNT,
     CYCLOMATIC-COMPLEXITY,
     CYCLIMATIC-DENSITY,
     DECISION-COUNT,
     DECISION-DENSITY,
     EDGE-COUNT,
     ESSENTIAL-COMPLEXITY,
     ESSENTIAL-DENSITY,
     LOC-EXECUTABLE,
     PARAMETER-COUNT,
     HALSTEAD-CONTENT,
     HALSREAD-DOFFICULTY,
     HALSTEAD-EFFORT,
     HALSTEAD-ERROR-EST,
     HALSTEAD-LENGTH,
     HALSTEAD LEVEL,
     HALSTEAD-VOLUME,
     MAINTENANCE-SEVERITY,
     MODIFIED-CONDITION-COUNT,
     MULTIPLE-CONDITION-COUNT,
     NODE-COUNT,
     NORMALIZED-CYCLOMATIC-COMPLEXITY,
     NUM-OPERANDS, 
     NUM-OPERATORS,
     NUM-UNIQUE-OPERANDS,
     NUM-UNIQYE-OPERATORS,
     NUMBER-OF-LINES,
     PERCENT-COMMENTS,
     LOC-TOTAL  \end{tabdescr} \\ \cmidrule{2-2}
                & \begin{tabdescr}\item{Dataset KC2} LOC-EXECUTABLE,
     CYCLOMATIC-COMPLEXITY,
     ESSENTIAL-COMPLEXITY,
     DESIGN-COMPLEXITY,
     NUM-OPERATORS-AND-OPERANDS,
     HALSTEAD-VOLUME,
     HALSTEAD-DIFFICULTY,
     HALSTEAD-INTEELIGENCE,
     HALSTEAD-EFFORT,
     HALSTEAD-NUM-DELIVERED-BUGS,
     HALSTEAD-PROG-TIME,
     HALSTEAD-CODE-LINE-COUNT,
     HALSTEAD-CODE-AND-COMMENT-LINE-COUNT,
     NUM-UNIQUE-OPERATORS,
     NUM-UNIQUE-OPERANDS,
     NUM-OPERATORS,
     NUM-OPERANDS,
     BRANCH-COUNT \end{tabdescr} \\ 
    \bottomrule                            
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work perfectly as needed, thanks for your effort

Comment: @Mai: What exactly does not work? Do you get any error messages upon compiling or does the code just not result in the desired output?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand at the first time that you introduced two tables, and both work fine, thank you.

Comment: your answer is correct too